# Simple jQuery syntax help, don't know where I've gone wrong

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with a jQuery code at the moment, I know WHERE the problem lies, but I don't know what the problem is exactly. Probably very basic, but I'm new to this.

You can see a (non)working fiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CvZeQ/

Basically I want to set different .click function based on whatever is selected (I have 5 image maps, each with a different #mapname, and want each to pertain to a different variable (answer1, answer2, answer3...) so as to store the selected 'answer' for each map.)

Here is the code I'm using for one of the maps:

```
  $(window).load(function(){
        //Get cookies when page loaded
        var useranswers=$.cookie('survery');
        useranswers= JSON.parse (useranswers);

        // do something with previous answers


        //#shape functions
        $('#shape area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            }
        ).click(
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
            },

            function(e){    
                var answer1 = $(this).attr("class");
            });

    });
```

I know the problem lies somewhere with the .click function, but I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.click()` doesn't accept three callbacks, it only accepts one. If you intend for all three to execute in sequence on click, try combining them all to a single `function(e)`, like so:

```
.click(
    function(e){
        $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
        $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
        var answer1 = $(this).attr("class");
    });
```

Also, change

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, although still not working - see here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CvZeQ/3/

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9t9AK remove your onload call... jsfiddle does this for you... Also you want to use onDomReady 99% of the time as opposed to onLoad.

Comment: Ahh, I'm an idiot. Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it mate! Upvotes for you.